# Why don't we stop users with low accept rates asking questions?

Tags: feature-request, accept-rate

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Don't allow people with very low accept rates to ask questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32553/dont-allow-people-with-very-low-accept-rates-to-ask-questions)
>   [Should users be discouraged from asking new questions until they've accepted a certain % or deleted old unaccepted questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28827/should-users-be-discouraged-from-asking-new-questions-until-theyve-accepted-a-ce)

What is more irritating than somebody who has asked 50 questions but only accepted 2 answers.

Why can people repeatedly ask questions whilst having a low accept rate?
Is it a bad idea to prevent a user with an accept rate under 10% from asking questions?

Why is it possible?

Comment: Asked before many times, for example: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32553/dont-allow-people-with-very-low-accept-rates-to-ask-questions

Comment: Sorry about that..

Comment: what a controversial topic!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok the purpose of this site is to ask questions and to get the best answers.

It is polite to accept and upvote the answers, but it is not required. So limiting the ability to ask questions because of the accept rate is a bad idea.

A suggestion to remind the question owner to accept can be a good idea. But there are other requests for that.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I'm totally against this.

This should be free community - we must not enforce our opinions on people.

We would like to have people accept answers that's right, but we're not living in ideal world. Most we can do is *suggest* people to improve the accept rate and tell them it will improve their chances of getting better help but that's it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm ok with a restriction because sure it is not a dictatorship but there is some rules..
And to be honest and accept answers who are useful is a kind of rule.
But I unserstand some people doesn't see the case in the same angle..

Answer (score -1):

I think this would be a great idea.

Because there alot of users just asking questions not accepting them and more importantly not even answering questions and getting rep off the questions.

Maybe instead they can't earn rep off questions they ask so that everybody wins.

Comment: You've been around long enough to now signatures aren't allowed.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think people should be blocked from asking questions if they have a low accept rate. Instead I think after about a week has passed since the first answer being posted, users should be able to vote for an accepted answer. Perhaps users need a certain amount of rep to be able to do this and then 5 votes accepts that answer. There have been numerous times when I've found a useful answer on an old question that has not been accepted and all you can do is upvote.

Comment: Yes interresting solution..!!

Comment: No, accepting is all about what helped the _OP_ most. No amount of rep will pay the crystal ball necessary for knowing what the OP would have chosen.

Comment: yes but question will maybe help someone else long time after..

Comment: @hendrik-vogt but if someone else asked the same question it would be closed as a duplicate, don't seem the harm that after a certain amount of time has lapsed, that user can vote for the answer.