# I flagged a "thank you" comment as "it's no longer needed" and it was autodeleted: was there a change I'm unaware of?

Tags: support, comments, flags

Just now I flagged a comment on [this answer](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/36668/8099) that said nothing other than ~"thank you, that's helpful" and it was deleted immediately.  I did not know this was a feature.  Moreover, I didn't find any documentation on this feature here at meta.SE.

**Question**: I flagged a "thank you" comment as it's "no longer needed" and it was auto-deleted: was there a change I'm unaware of?

I'd be particularly interested in understanding precisely how this feature works.

This comment was not offensive nor was it spam, just a run-of-the-mill "thank you" comment.  I don't recall this happening for previous "it's no longer needed" flags.  I'm sure it was *a single flag* that caused this, because it's a 5-month old post.

If I knew precisely what was going on, I'd pay a bit more attention to flagging these.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [flagged comments disappear instantly ... what's going on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121225/flagged-comments-disappear-instantly-whats-going-on)

Comment: See [Why do comment flags sometimes take immediate effect?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266161/4642212).

Comment: This is answered in our FAQ [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work): *Comments containing certain keywords can be deleted with a single flag.*. It's also possible that this may not be on the list of keywords, but that others also flagged it.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/15292/282094  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204402/282094

Comment: "Thanks" is definitely part of the single flag delete rules but only when the comments are very short. :)