# Want to flag for deletion - cannot, want to flag for moderator, cannot

Tags: support

I want to delete

[Please help test a CORS issue in Firefox jQuery ajax when 401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290068/please-help-test-a-cors-issue-in-firefox-jquery-ajax-when-401)

Cannot delete since it has answers (which did not answer the question and just cost bounty)
Cannot flag a mod since it seems I already did. If I did I do not remember getting any attention

What are my options here?

thanks

Comment: People who downvote without any comment as to why should REALLY not have the rights to downvote - especially not in META where questions are asked because something does not make sense to the asker. Shame on you, whoever you are.

Comment: IMO questions should stay, much like Mark explained below. If people will start deleting their old questions just because they don't like it anymore, too much information will be lost. However I don't think you should be downvoted as you only asked what are your options, rectified this by upvoting. :)

Comment: Thanks :) And I agree to keep questions that have value for the community. In this case the only value is to show that there might be an issue, but there is no valid answer.

Comment: a downvote in Meta just means disagreement.  It does not have the same meaning as other downvotes.  Secondly, there are several questions on SO that deal with why comments are not required for downvotes and the reasons why downvoting should be encouraged more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have a lot of options, but before I mention what they are, it's helpful to explain why everything you tried so far hasn't worked:

When you create a question or answer on Stack Overflow, you cede some of your rights under the [Creative Commons license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/) you were required to accept to publish new content.

One of those rights is the ability to cease distribution of your work provided the distributor meets all the criteria of the license. The benefit is that the community can rely on content remaining there for posterity.

That is, in exchange for others helping you (or you gaining reputation), what you publish on Stack Overflow needs to remain accessible as a resource to others who need help.

So your only real option is to e-mail team@stackoverflow.com and ask them to disassociate your account from the question (this might actually require [deleting your account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26844/there-needs-to-be-a-way-to-delete-content-or-disassociate-your-account-from-said/26853#26853)). Your content stays, but you would at least no longer be associated with it on the live site.

But realize what happens on the internet in public stays on the internet in public. Even after any action is taken on your account or question, there are months and months of archives that still have the association between you and the question. It is likely that it will never go away.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just do not want an, in my mind not-answered question, to hang about for so long since it lowers my percentage of accepted answers. But it was also a question of why my "ask attention" was not visibly attended to. The downvote reaction to this question raises more questions

Comment: @mplungjan You were likely downvoted because deleting content is unwanted for the reasons mentioned in my answer, and down-votes on meta usually mean ["I don't like this idea"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42558). Your flag was likely dismissed as invalid as your accept rate and the question being unanswered aren't justification enough to delete a question. For what it's worth, your 80% accept rate is [more than fine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16712/a/16716#16716): if someone's giving you flak for it, that person is an a-hole.

Comment: Right. I am ok with ceding rights, however I also want to clean up questions, to keep my doorstep clean so to speak. If the question is too hard to answer with the information given, then I feel I should remove it to not clutter SO. Also, asking a question that relates to something unpopular or such should not result in a downvote, but an answer or a comment. Ah. I read the post about the downvote. Sigh. Another unpleasantness at SO.

Comment: @mplungjan That's not how Stack Overflow or the Creative Commons license works: it's up to the community to decide, not solely you, what's worthwhile to keep.

Comment: But they could still agree. Enough people agree on "off topic" removal, so why can't I flag my own question for deletion, just because there is an answer? Does not make sense. Flagging it shows my opinion about my own question, perhaps others that see my flag agrees and a quorum is formed.

Comment: @mplungjan when you flag a question, it's flagging it for moderator review. A moderator is a trusted member of the community who has been chosen/elected because of their ability to understand the will and collective interests of the community: if they won't on your flag, it's because deleting your question is not in the interest of the community. However, if you had [enough reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools), you'd be able to do what you're asking: the ability vote to delete is given to high rep users because deletion isn't something that should be taken lightly.

Comment: Okee, i need another 30 rep for 3K... :)