# How can I hide the acceptance rate?

Tags: support, accept-rate

My questions all say "0% accept rate" ([example](https://superuser.com/questions/37049/what-is-the-lifetime-of-a-typical-hard-disk)). Although this is correct, the rate apparently is not always published ([example](https://superuser.com/questions/37144/how-to-beep-on-tail-f-event)). I'd like to hide it too. How can I do so?

**Note:** [I don't like the feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18054/isnt-the-accepted-answer-feature-overly-visible), because I don't like to decide for other users what The Right Answer is.

Comment: In a bout of hilarious irony, methinks you didn't read the responses to your initial post, because there are some very, very good ones.

Comment: @Eric: I did read them, and I still don't agree. I know I am being stubborn, but I thought there was a hiding feature when I saw the acceptance rate is not shown for all questions.

Comment: As to the note: You're not deciding for other users. You're deciding for you. You're saying, "This answer solved my problem. Thank you, kind sir or madam." Again: You need to read the responses to your original MSO post about this.

Comment: @Eric: I find the accepted answer too visible. I'dd gladly use the feature if it were kept invisible for other users.

Comment: That's like saying, "I don't like my credit rating. How can I hide it from lenders?"

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351925 Mine is a technical description, and while accurate, didn't help the OP understand. The answer has a lower vote total, but helped the OP grok what a modulo was. If you don't know what a modulo is, wouldn't you want the one that helped explain it best to the original asker than one that happens to be technically correct? I do, and this community does. And that makes your refusal to use it aggravating to those that answer your questions and those that see them after you've left them.

Comment: Who *are* you asking questions for?

Comment: Is this in any way related to this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20696/handling-problematic-stack-overflow-participants ?

Comment: Your questions on SuperUser look pretty subjective to me, which is why you've probably not accepted any answers. Maybe ask a question or two with a definitive answer you could actually accept?

Comment: @random: I don't think Dimitri is a problematic user. He fulfills one of Jeff's points, but his questions got upvotes and he also answers.

Comment: @Jared Harley: Hm. Maybe. However, I don't consider the question "How to test your backups against medium degeneration?" subjective for example. However, I don't know what *the* answer is to that question, even when I'll see it.

Comment: @Dimitri: You aren't trying to select *the* answer to that question. You're selecting the answer that helped you test your backups against medium degeneration. It may not be the greatest way to do it, but it's the way that solved your problem. And that's the point.

Comment: @Eric: You're right. Maybe just misinterpret the big V and the fact it gets listed even before the answer with the top vote.

Comment: I am wondering whether I should accept one of the answers, as they sound perfectly reasonable to me :p

Comment: If you are confronting an *actual* problem when you ask your question (ie. something that came up at work or home) and you *solve* that problem, then you select the answer from SU that gave you the biggest help. If more than one answer helped you, then accept the one that helped you the most.

Comment: You don't. It's that simple.

Answer (score 17):

Let's see:

- never ask more than 3 questions.
- make all your questions community wiki.

That's about it.

Comment: This answer is *right*, it should be accepted.

Comment: But then Dimitri C. would be pushing his opinion on the rest of us!!!

Answer (score 9):

You can't.

The feature is not there for you, ***the feature is there for us.***  It is there for those of us who may (or may not) want to spend the time answering your questions.

Comment: That's not my issue. I am glad to upvote good answers to my questions, and it would be fine if this upvoting behaviour is made visible in the user interface. However, I don't want to push my opinion of what is The Right Answer so visibly.

Comment: It is your issue, no?  You are the one who does not like this feature.  Stop thinking 'me' and start thinking 'us'.

Answer (score 9):

Dimitri C.,

There is another point of view I would like you to consider.

This service is provided to you free of charge. The people who help you, they do it free of charge. The questions and answers are all available free of charge. But "free of charge" refers only to financial remuneration. There is *one* way you compensate the system and its users for the time and expense they put into it; **by providing content.**

*Content* doesn't just include the questions and answers you provide, but the value-added information you provide by participating in the community. Your votes, your comments, your profile, your reputation; they all add value to the system. And **accepting answers adds value to the system**.

Now, no one "requires" you to participate in any of these activities. They are strictly voluntary. But the behavior of the system is **designed to *encourage* activities** that are best for the community.

Regarding "accepted answers": You choose *not* to participate because you do not agree with it. That is your choice. But you are also, in a sense, **abstaining from providing a bit of "compensation"** that users might expect for their efforts. Users have a right to know that up front. Not have it "hidden" from them.

In one of my comments, I quipped that hiding your your acceptance rate is like saying, "*I don't like my credit rating. How can I hide it from lenders?*" I feel that that analogy is apt.

Comment: +1 for the credit rating analogy

Answer (score 8):

The fact that you have 0% accept rate just shows that you don't like the feature. If you're happy for it to be widely known, why do you care whether it's published or not? It gives an answerer the information that you're very unlikely to accept any answers. This is true, isn't it?

Admittedly there's also the *implication* that you're unlikely to be particularly active in terms of responding to answers, adding comments, editing your questions etc. That implication may well not be true for you, but there's *usually* a correlation.

The reason it's not published for some users is that they haven't asked enough questions for it to be statistically relevant.

Answer (score 4):

The acceptance rate is not there for your benefit, its there to display the information to the public, allowing them to make an informed decision. Additionally, [as Jeff says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20701/how-can-i-hide-the-acceptance-rate/20704#20704), if you [don't want your percentage shown](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/), you have to have less than 4 questions that:

- are > 3 days old
- are not community wiki
- have at least one answer provided

People like gaining reputation and badges, by not accepting answers, you are hindering them from gaining both of these. While you are entitled to your choices for your own reasons, other people should also be allowed to make an informed choice.

Comment: I like to give people extra reputation for helping me out, but I don't like the fact that I can select The Right Answer.

Comment: @Dimitri, I understand that's your opinion and approach, and you're entitled to it. However, the SO system is trying to encourage you in the other direction. You can still choose to ignore it, but the system is going to point it out, unless you work within the constraints listed above.

Comment: @yshuditelu: I fully agree with you.