# Is there an established etiquette for asking someone to 'select' your answer if they've effectively done so in the comments?

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you feel dirty if you nudge new users to accept your answer when they indicate you've answered their question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994/do-you-feel-dirty-if-you-nudge-new-users-to-accept-your-answer-when-they-indicate)

So, in reference to this question:
[web page layout issue in firefox 3.6 /mac os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744532/web-page-layout-issue-in-firefox-3-6-mac-os/3744596#3744596)

...the user who asked the question indicated that I had answered her question, but did not check it as answered.

Now, this is not the end of the world or anything, but this is the first time someone has 'chosen' my answer, and I'd love for it to actually show up in my profile. I indicated in reply to the "asker's" comment that I would appreciate it if she checked my answer...

My question is:

1. Is it ok to ask someone to check your answer as I did?

and/or

2. Is there an established etiquette for this kind of situation that I should follow instead of / in addition to what I already did?

Finally, I read through the stack exchange FAQ and I believe I correctly understood 'Meta Stack Overflow' to be the appropriate place to ask this question, but I apologize if I misunderstood. If I'm incorrect in where I've asked this question, could you please direct me to the appropriate place to ask it?

Thank you!

Comment: Yep, Meta is just the right place for this -- and it has already been asked :)

Comment: also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20722/what-is-with-people-not-marking-their-questions-as-answered

Comment: Ah, sorry, searched but didn't see it. Thanks!

Comment: Don't worry -- I *knew* it was there, and even I had to search a while :)