# A separate "rep-account" for bounties (set and received)

Tags: feature-request, reputation, bounties, stackexchange-2.0

With all the new sites around chances are high one has little reputation on a site where one still has one question that could call for a bounty. It has been [suggested before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7193/146482) to use rep from another site to set a bounty so I don't repeat that here. My idea is instead:

> One bounty-account where reputation received from awarded bounties (and only such!) can be put to and which can then be used on any other SE site to set new bounties.

This would support replying to bounty questions by offering a special kind of rep that can be used on other SE sites as well instead of only on the specific site, without meddling with the privileges.

---

**edit** Taking into account [Pekka's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80061/a-separate-rep-account-for-bounties-set-and-received/80062#80062) regarding the potential unfairness on the need to have gained bounty-rep by bounties (which may happen seldom and cause too much competition), I suggest the following addition:

> ... Also, reputation up to the total amount of bounties previously manually awarded on one site can be "withdrawn" from that sites account to the bounty account.

That would also support the bounty system in total by encouraging users to set bounties on each site.

<sub>Now I know loosening this further would be `allow to put rep from any site to the bounty account (maybe at some not-1:1 exchange rate)`, but that would render this feature-request into an almost-duplicate of [Allow bounty to be set with reputation from another site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7193/146482)</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe it's me, but to me this seems a bit unfair.

Being able to post bounties on other sites - where one is not as knowledgeable as on, say, SO, and maybe actually needs help - would be a great thing.

But why should that be limited to users who happen to gain reputation through bounties on their home site? That seems to limit the circle of people who can ask bounty questions on other sites in a rather arbitrary way. What about the thousands of users who are tirelessly active, but have never been rewarded with a bounty?

For the record though, I find this a very interesting idea and a direction worth exploring, even though I don't think the current form is practicable.

Comment: I noticed a [cross-site bounty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7193/146482) feature-request is already in place and strongly support it, but since that might be considered abusable so I thought this kind of restricted cross-site-bounty-from-received-bounties-only would limit this possibility. But you're right, it _is_ a bit too restricted probably. Maybe something in between would be accepted by the SE team?

Comment: @Tobias I like the idea of doing cross-site bounties with a currency that is outside the normal rep currency - something like that would sort most potential abuse issues. This is surely an interesting direction to think in. But it *would* have to be possible to somehow start those bounties with normal rep... Hmm.

Comment: see my edit. Either one can also use rep up the amount of bounties set up so far, or introduce some exchange rate privilege-rep to bounty-rep

Comment: I agree with your concerns. I answer an awful lot of questions on SO, but I don't know that I've ever been awarded a bounty. Maybe I answer things too quickly...?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I believe that rep on different sites are different currencies, so the exchange rate is not necessarily 1:1.

I'm not sure if that invalidates your idea or not...

Comment: probably true, but I think any exchange rate that is not 1:1 is _very_ subjective

Comment: @Tobias I wouldn't think that Seasoned Advice and Gaming are very much on a 1:1 exchange rate, and neither strikes me as dangerously subjective. They're just entirely independent practices, and quite frankly trying to apply knowledge from one across to the other tends to result in disasters.