# Transfer points between SE sites, purely for use as a bounty

Tags: feature-request, bounties, rep-transfer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow bounty to be set with reputation from another site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7193/allow-bounty-to-be-set-with-reputation-from-another-site)

What do people think about being able to offer a bounty on site A using reputation earned on site B?

I have a 2.2k reputation at StackOverflow and have a very Ubuntu specific question on askUbuntu.com that I could really do with being answered - it's not programming-related at all. Sadly this question has no answers so far, and, because it's specific to a certain type of hardware, I'm not particularly hopeful for the future. This is where a bounty would be used, but I only have enough reputation to offer a bounty if I take into account my points at StackOverflow.

I agree that transferring reputation between sites is, on the whole, undesirable (reputation is, after all, about your reputation on the site where you have earned that reputation), but perhaps this could be the exception to that rule? I still wouldn't have suitable reputation to do administrative-style tasks on AskUbuntu (rightly leaving that to the Ubuntu users who have rightly-earned reputation), but I'd still be able to encourage someone to help me with my problem.

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm sure this has been asked for before, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: Damn, I searched and searched and couldn't find the "possible duplicate" which is definitely a definite duplicate!