# Stack Exchange Rep Transferable for bounty purposes?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, bounties, rep-transfer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow bounty to be set with reputation from another site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7193/allow-bounty-to-be-set-with-reputation-from-another-site)

Can the reputation earned on one stack Exchange site be used for hosting bounties in another?

Comment: but there is no definite answer on that other topic or even an indication of an implementation in this regard

Comment: That means the request is still open/pending. Closing as dupe on Meta is partly meant to consolidate the discussion of a topic into a single question.

Comment: @Jon Thank you for clarifying this