# Can I use my rep from one site to give a bounty on another

Tags: feature-request, bounties, site-crossover

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow bounty to be set with reputation from another site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7193/allow-bounty-to-be-set-with-reputation-from-another-site)

I had a pressing database question, so I posted it on stackoverflow.
However no useful answer came and I offered a bounty.

Answers came along with the remark:

> This is better asked on dba.stackexchange.com

And indeed it was, however I have no rep on `dba` to reward a bounty whilst I have oodles of rep on SO.

Why can't I use my rep from SO on another SE site?