# Can't start bounty but have enough reputation?

Tags: support, bounties

Yesterday I asked a question on SuperUser and it happened to have 55 views and no answers so far!

When I wanted to start a bounty I realized that unlike my stackoverflow account there is no 'Start a bounty' link down there because of my low repu; hence asking the question here!

Is something like this going to be implemented?

Comment: Note: you do have the required reputation (you only need 75), you just need to wait longer as jonsca points out.

Comment: p.s., Setting bounties using reputation from another site [is declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7193/allow-bounty-to-be-set-with-reputation-from-another-site).  Transferring reputation between sites is in all liklihood, [not going to happen](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93868/transfer-reputation-to-your-own-account-on-a-differnet-s-e-site).

Comment: Thanks for clarification ( -- and for down-votes! :p )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have enough rep.  You need to [wait 48 hours](https://superuser.com/faq) to be able to set a bounty on your question.

Answer (score 2):

I would say no because reputation is separate for every stack because if I'm a great programmer and a bad mathematician then I should  NOT have a good rep on the math stack and the reverse applies to I wouldn't want people to think I was a bad programmer because I am a a bad mathematician

Comment: *if I'm a great programmer and a **bad mathematician** then I should have a **good rep** on the **math** stack* - are you sure that's what you meant? O.o

Comment: @david Thomas thanks I missed that

Answer (score 1):

When I checked few minutes ago, the reputation you had on SuperUser was 111, and the minimum reputation necessary to set a bounty is 75. The problem is not the reputation but, as @jonsca said, the fact you need to wait, before to set a bounty for your question.