# Catch-22: Can't add bounty to old question on meta

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, bounties

I want to add a bounty to this question:

[Allow bounty to be set with reputation from another site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7193/allow-bounty-to-be-set-with-reputation-from-another-site)

It is a very useful feature request that has many upvotes and the most upvoted answer agrees with the proposal. The purpose of the bounty would be to attract attention to the question, so that it hopefully changes from [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) to something else, or at least to get an (official?) explanation why it is declined.

The catch-22 is that in order to use my rep from SO to add the bounty, the question suggestion would have to be [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Any ideas?

Comment: Your worries are no more, I have bountied the question. Cheers!

Comment: What do you imagine a bounty on a feature request is going to accomplish? Do you think the stackexchange devs are going to suddenly add the feature because they want some rep?

Comment: @Wooble A bounty on a feature request can be useful to give it some extra attention. And possibly to get some additional input from the community on the suggested feature. I have done so in the past.

Comment: To change a declined feature new evidence being useful should be delivered. I don't think that only adding a bounty changes anything.

Comment: The bounty will be an additional incentive for people to also add new arguments in favor of the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In situations like this, ask for help. Every single site has chat rooms in which you can find helpful people - at least some users should be willing to help you out, as I have done on the question you linked.

Comment: I didn't think of using the chat for this. Good point. Hopefully the bounty will make a difference and it won't be necessary next time :P

Comment: @user000001 I honestly wouldn't count on it. The SE team is slow to change big features like that, and while it appears on the outside that it was only Jeff who declined the request, I doubt they would go and do something like that, even after he's left.

Comment: Nothing really changed since 2009 on that specific case; the reason for declining is pretty obvious to me: each site is focused on something else; being a good programmer does not mean you are a good cook and reputation on one site does not indicate anything in other sites. Bottom line, that is one request that I can say for 99.999% sure that won't ever get implemented.