# Borrowing points from one Stack Exchange account for bounty on another?

Tags: support, bounties, user-accounts, merge-accounts, rep-transfer

I don't see an answer to this [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work), so:

Can I borrow points from one Stack Exchange site for a bounty on another?

Specifically, I want to move some points from one of my other Stack Exchange accounts so that I can start a bounty on a question I posted at Super User, where I only have 38 points.

Comment: Nope, you cannot.

Comment: Dang, you must work for Amazon - I think you answered my question before I posted it.

Comment: Points from one Stack Exchange account are representative of your helpfulness on that particular Stack Exchange site.  They have no currency on any other Stack Exchange site, other than your ability to get an association bonus when you register on a new site.

Comment: That doesn't sound fair now.. I mean, bounties are a sort of privilege for the ponts you earn

Comment: @Adel So if I get lots of rep on bicycles.SE, I can put a +500 bounty on my programming question of "what is best language?"

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow - I'm with you amigo. I am also against the borrowing idea

Comment: Odd that this is a duplicate when I binged "Can i borrow points from one stack exchange site for a bounty on another?" and found nothing pertinent.

Comment: @Adel Oops, misread comment :-P

Comment: Well, can we redeem our points for beer and pizza? And if not, when are we going to implement this important feature??

Answer (score 8):

I'm sure the fine folks on Physics.stackexchange.com will agree that my huge reputation here on Meta makes me an expert in Physics.

Comment: And of course my SO rep makes me amazing at photography and bicycles.

Comment: Actually, the suggested feature would not increase *your* physics rep, it would ultimately increase the rep of the one who is awarded the bounty for their answer. And if your physics question lingers around long enough without receiving an answer it seems not to be so stupid or close-wotthy at all

Answer (score 6):

No, each site is essentially isolated from the other sites, as far as reputation is concerned. You cannot transfer bounties from reputation earned elsewhere.

The only exception is the association bonus which is given to you because you've learned the basics of the Stack Exchange model.

If you *could* transfer reputation, then anyone with an account on a busy site such as Stack Overflow could monopolize attention on a smaller site. I could use my 200k on Stack Overflow to buy a lot of eyeballs over on, say, Pets.stackexchange.com. That would not be fair to the other regular Pets supporters without a big fat SO account to draw from.

Comment: A lot of things are day-limited, such as question/answer voting, reputation earned in a day, etc; Aside from the problem that each SE community is isolated, the problem that you mentioned about monopolizing the attention could easily be solved with bounty borrowed reputation limited to once a week.

Comment: That still would allow you to monopolise the attention, because you can still afford much larger bounties than other users. And limiting it to once a week is useless, bounties last for a week already, you just keep adding a new bounty once a week from your endless siteXwithLargeReputationAmount pool each time.