# How about tipping users on Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-exchange

I recently sent an email to SE Team, offering the idea to allow "tips" on Stack Exchange sites. They advised me to post it here, since SE is maintained and build by the community.

Below is an email text, that sent to SE Team, and I would like to hear what the great Stack Exchange community is thinking about allowing Dogecoin "tips" on SE sites:

> *Hello SE Team,*
>
> *It's a first time I'm writing to this email, and the first thing that I want, is to thank you for a great service and site you're providing!
>   You have a great community sites, that helps me each day multiple
>   times and actually, I don't know what would I do, if Stack Overflow
>   would not exists. And I'm sure I am not alone with my feelings. 
>   Again, great work and thank you!*
>
> *Now for a business :)   I'm sure geniuses like you, heard about Bitcoin like cryptocurrencies, and Dogecoin especially
>   (http://dogecoin.com/). In case of not, Dogecoin is an alternative to
>   Bitcoin currency that grows very fast and has a huge community.
>   Dogecoin exists less then two months, but community counts almost 70k
>   members on reddit (http://www.reddit.com/r/dogecoin/).*
>
> *What I think, it would be a great thing, if it would be possible to make Dogecoin "tips" on Stack Exchange sites. Not just up-voting a
>   good answers, but send some "tip" to person who helps to solve the
>   problems. I don't think it's something hard to implement, since there
>   already exists the tipping bot that works on Reddit, Twitter,  Youtube
>   and more.*
>
> *In my opinion, such service can be as useful for Dogecoin as for Stack Overflow. As a beta, it could be used on
>   https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/ and if it proves yourself, it can
>   move further for other SE sites.*
>
> *Thank you, hope you will like it and we will see Dogecoin on Stack Exchange soon!   Regards,   Alex Danilov*

**Edit:** After receiving some comments, I think it important to state that Dogecoin is not a "real currency" and do not want to be. It is a "virtual tipping value". As huge Dogecoin community states: 1 Dodge = 1 Doge :)

Comment: You can already add info to your profile, stating you wouldn't mind receiving a tip, and how others could best tip you. There's no problem in doing that.

Comment: So, *money* for answers? That's never going to happen.

Comment: This could easily lead to a decrease in quality: people would start giving the answers that they hope will earn them quick money, instead of answering the actual question.

Comment: Actually, I am not exactly interested in received tips by myself. I think about an integrating tip bot on SE sites so everyone can tip each other and the tips activity is visible to all members. Exactly as voting.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I don't think it will lead to this, since the "real value" of the tips is very small. It exactly what happening with votes...we have many non quality answers, just to get SE points, but the community decide what to vote up and down.

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby I don't think it's the same. The Dogecoin community especially states that 1 Doge = 1 Doge :)

Answer (score 13):

SE uses a lot of gamification elements, but the important distinction to what you propose is that there is never any real money involved. You get shiny badges and meaningless internet points for your efforts, but not more.

I only know Dogecoin from hearsay, but as far as I know it has some non-zero value in real currencies, at least for the moment, so I'll treat this as if it were real money for this post.

The existing mechanisms already lead to a certain amount of abuse due to users trying to inflate their reputation or trying to game certain badges. Imagine how much worse this could get if real money got involved there.

This is not a site where you get paid for answering questions, and I think that is an important psychological aspect. Most users answer questions because they enjoy it, or because they want to give back to the community. They get some positive feedback in form of badges or reputation, but not any real money. If we would get real money for answering, this would change the whole dynamic, and I don't think this is a good thing.

So I personally would oppose any mechanism that would lead to users earning real money for their participation, and that includes the doge coin tips you proposed.

Comment: As I wrote in the comment above, 1 Doge = 1 Doge, and the purpose of the Dogecoin is not to become a "real currency". As I know, Dogecoin community wants it to be "internet tipping coin". So it will possible to gain some "virtual" value on SE and then be able to give that same value somewhere else, like Youtube or Twitter...

Comment: @AlexDn If Dogecoin has no real monetary value, then what is the difference with upvotes and bounties?

Comment: @AlexDn I just looked at the [Dogecoin Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogecoin) and it states that Dogecoin has a market capitalization of $81 million.

Comment: @S.L.Barth the main difference is about upvotes and bounties are SE sites only and Dogecoin can be something that can be usable in whole internet.

Comment: Yes it has a capitalization graphs, but it came not because the community work on gaining the "real value". The market capitalization value it a case of demand of the coins. Many people want it, but currently there not many places where you can get it. So you need to mine it or buy it. If SE will allow tipping with Dogecoins, that will an additional source where people can get them.

Comment: @AlexDn It has been proposed to [use points earned on one SE site to set bounties in other SE sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7193/allow-bounty-to-be-set-with-reputation-from-another-site). This has been declined. You propose a system that is even wider, outside the control of Stack Exchange. I really don't want people to use kudos earned on opinion-based sites to steer Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @Alex-dn As a dogecoin enthousiast myself, I think I have to agree with Mad Scienetist that it is certainly possible to use Dogecoin tips as a way to gain money. This could fundamentally change the SE dynamic and I'm not sure it would be for the better. I'm all for dogecoin, but I am not sure this is the best thing for SE.